# How to assign an issue to non contributors?

Tags: github

Is it possible to assign an issue to non-contributors on a project?

I have a project that others want to work on, but I'm the only one that can get assigned.

Comment: Note: this has changed in June 2019. See my edited answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Update June 2019, three years later:

You could ask that non-contributor to... leave a comment on the issue.
Because then, you can [**Assign issues to issue commenters**](https://github.blog/changelog/2019-06-25-assign-issues-to-issue-commenters/):

> Now, when a user with read-only access to a repository comments on an issue, a maintainer of that repository can assign the issue to that user.
>
> If the user does not want to be assigned to the issue, they may unassign themselves by clicking unassign me next to their name.

---

Original answer Dec. 2016:

The [official rule](https://help.github.com/articles/assigning-issues-and-pull-requests-to-other-github-users/) is:

> You can only create assignments for yourself, [collaborators on personal projects](https://help.github.com/articles/how-do-i-add-a-collaborator), or [members of your organization](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-teams) with read permissions on the repository.

So if you can [add other users as collaborators to your repo,](https://help.github.com/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/) you will be able to assign to them issues.